# Basic Background service tries to open a socket

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm trying to have an app which simply starts a background service whenever a button is pressed. The background app should then open a connection using a socket to a server and then send some dummy data. After having done so, the service should die.

I'm currently getting a `java.lang.IllegalStateException` when I click the button and the whole application stops.
Here is what I have so far in my main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }


  public void start_clicked(View view) {
    Intent my_intent = new Intent(this,BackgroundService.class);
    startActivity(my_intent);
  }
}
```

Here is the XML corresponding to the button and to the background service:
This is Activity_Main.xml

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="start_clicked"/>
```

This is the Android Manifest corresponding to the service

```
<service android:name="com.example.g.backgroundsensor.BackgroundService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true" >
</service>
```

And finally here is the actual BackgroundService class (fragments which I think caused the error)

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

private Socket my_socket;

public BackgroundService() {
    try {
        my_socket = new Socket(ip, 5000);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    try {
        DataOutputStream my_stream = new DataOutputStream(my_socket.getOutputStream());
        my_stream.write(121);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    stopSelf();
    return 1;
}
```

What is causing this error and how could I (in the future) debug this myself since the console is relatively vague:

```
---/com.example.g.backgroundsensor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
---/com.example.g.backgroundsensor E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.g.backgroundsensor, PID: 9876

---/com.example.g.backgroundsensor E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to create a Intent Service instead of service because intent service is called on UI thread and android doesn't allow any network call on UI thread take a look at code below

```
public class SocketService extends IntentService {

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
       //CONNECT SOCKET HERE
    }
}
```

then register this service in Manifest

```
<application>
<service android:name=".SocketService" />
</application>
```

and then start your service like this

`startService(new Intent(this, SocketService.class));
//YOU HAVE USED startActivity INSTEAD OF startService`

Answer (score 4):

To start a `Service` you should use `startService()` and not `startActivity()`

```
Intent my_intent = new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class);
startService(my_intent);
```

I don't know how one would debug that, but you should always make sure what you are calling where and which arguments you are passing.

Comment: Seems it's running but not doing anything. I have tested the ip from another device and it does connect however the android does not connect. Does this have anything to do with my service code or the actual socket code? (Sorry for late response)

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar app and my Manifest only contains this:

```
<service android:name=".ServiceActivity" />
```

inside the application tag, just before activity tag. Besides that, your Manifest should explicit:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in this code.

1. To start a service that should run in background you need started service hence you need to call startservice() :

   Intent my_intent = new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class);
   startService(my_intent);
2. Second big problem is that the way you have created your service. It will by default start on UI thread. So, in this scenario you should have either use IntentService or service on a separate thread.

Intent Service :

```
    public class BackgroundService extends IntentService {
        private Socket my_socket;
        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
            try {
                my_socket = new Socket(ip, 5000);
                DataOutputStream my_stream = new DataOutputStream(my_socket.getOutputStream());
                my_stream.write(121);
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    }
```

Major benefit of intent service is that it will call stopSelf once all the work is done and there are no more requests. Second is that all the work will be done in background.

Service on a seperate thread :

```
    public class BackgroundService extends Service {
      private Looper mServiceLooper;
      private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

      // Handler that receives messages from the thread
      private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
          public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
              super(looper);
          }
          @Override
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
              // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
              public class HelloService extends Service {
  private Looper mServiceLooper;
  private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

  // Handler that receives messages from the thread
  private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
      public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
          super(looper);
      }
      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
          // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
          // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
          try {
              Thread.sleep(5000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              // Restore interrupt status.
              Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
          }
          // Stop the service using the startId, so that we don't stop
          // the service in the middle of handling another job
          stopSelf(msg.arg1);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    // Start up the thread running the service.  Note that we create a
    // separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
    // main thread, which we don't want to block.  We also make it
    // background priority so CPU-intensive work will not disrupt our UI.
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments",
            Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();

    // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
    mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      // For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the
      // start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job
      Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
      msg.arg1 = startId;
      mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

      // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
      return START_STICKY;
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      // We don't provide binding, so return null
      return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
              // Stop the service using the startId, so that we don't stop
              // the service in the middle of handling another job
              stopSelf(msg.arg1);
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
        // Start up the thread running the service.  Note that we create a
        // separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
        // main thread, which we don't want to block.  We also make it
        // background priority so CPU-intensive work will not disrupt our UI.
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments",
                Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        thread.start();

        // Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
        mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
      }

      @Override
      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          // For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the
          // start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job
          Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
          msg.arg1 = startId;
          mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

          // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
          return START_STICKY;
      }

      @Override
      public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
          // We don't provide binding, so return null
          return null;
      }

      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    }
```

I would suggest using intentservice as it is simple and perfect for your scenario.

Comment: I modified it so that it uses `startService` however it still doesn't connect. I looked in the network activity graph in my IDE and there seems to be 0. Is the service not starting or is my socket code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

*What is causing this error*

`startActivity` is called instead of `startService`

*how could I (in the future) debug this myself since the console is relatively vague*

This is the interesting part, the message should be followed by a full stack trace, that is explicitly describing the error. Like this one :

```
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214): Process: com.example.sandbox, PID: 16214
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4458)
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4453)
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    ... 9 more
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.sandbox/com.example.sandbox.BackgroundService}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1794)
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3930)
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3890)
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4213)
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4181)
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at com.example.sandbox.MainActivity.start_clicked(MainActivity.java:19)
02-10 12:26:52.734: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    ... 11 more
```

The part `Unable to find explicit activity class com.example.sandbox/com.example.sandbox.BackgroundService}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` is very clear and it should be easy to fix the issue just reading it.